# Getting CORS blocked even after ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

Tags: ajax, express

I am getting CORS blocked regardless of what I allow. It only yells at me for my POST route, my GET routes it allows just fine. I consistently get

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://simple-startup-survey-backend.herokuapp.com/client_answers' from origin 'http://simple-startup-survey.surge.sh' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am using an AJAX to communicate with an EXPRESS server. I allow all requests with the wildcard operator. I have tried sending {crossDomain: true} with my request.

//This is my backend in app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH,PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

// This is my front end AXIOS call POST request. This is what is //triggering the CORS block

```
 storedData = storedData.concat(storedData2)
     axios.post('https://simple-startup-survey-backend.herokuapp.com/client_answers', {crossDomain:true}, storedData,)
     .then(function(response){
       console.log(response.data , ' save success')
       localStorage.setItem("storedData", JSON.stringify(storedData))
       window.location.href = "../AnalysisPage/analysis.html";
     }).catch()
   })
```

// This is my perfectly functional GET request. It does a bunch of //stuff after this in the .then, but I don't think that is relevant to //this issue

```
function getgeneralQuestions(){
    axios.get('https://simple-startup-survey-backend.herokuapp.com/questions/balanceSheet')
    .then(function (response) {
```

Every damn Google search result on the planet says that what I have in regards to my back end should work. I am using vanilla JS, no JQUERY.
Any help greatly appreciated!

back end Github: https://github.com/TuckerNemcek/SimpleSurveyBackend

front end Github: https://github.com/TuckerNemcek/SimpleStartupSurveyProject

Answer (score 1):

I am running into a similar issue.

My hunch is that surge.sh does not have cors enabled on its server.

My website is actually making the request correctly.
Afterward there is an error and the data is not shown.

Edit: Solved - - - -

Actually, just solved this for myself!
This is my script for publishing.

```
yarn build; cp build/index.html build/200.html; echo '*' > build/CORS; surge build appname.surge.sh
```

here is an article about enabling cors for surge.sh https://github.com/surge-sh/example-cors

Also when making changes make sure you are in a new incognito tab each time or go to the network tab on dev tools and Disable cache otherwise your app might be lying to you and thing cors is not enabled when it in fact is enabled.